# Characterization of roots for a cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I have been trying to characterize the roots of the equation

> $$ f(x) =  x \left(1-x^2 \right) + \left(1+x^2 \right) \frac{\sum w_i y_i }{n}  - x \frac{\sum w_i^2 + \sum y_i^2}{n} = 0 $$

where the $w$s and $y$s are real numbers and $x$ has to lie in the interval $[-1, 1]$. Now since the function is continuous and changes signs between $-1$ and $1$, there is at least one root and there can be as many as three. My book, nevertheless, claims that the equation can have *at most* two such solutions. If anyone sees how this is true, I would appreciate some help understanding it. Thank you.

Comment: The whole thing is cubic, so there are at most 3 roots total. My guess would be that you should show that there is one outside this interval.

Comment: What makes you say that it changes sign ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. In the special case $w_i = y_i = 0$, we have $f(x) = -(x + 1) x (x - 1)$, which has three roots in the interval $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, $f(-1) = \frac{1}{n} \sum (w_i + y_i)^2 >0 $ and $f(1) = -\frac{1}{n} \sum (w_i - y_i)^2 <0 $

Comment: @JohnK: quite right, I forgot an $x$ factor.

Comment: @Travis Thanks, it struck me as odd too. This textbook is known to contain mistakes so this might be one of them.

Comment: Maybe what your book means is that, other than the special case when $x=0$, if your cubic has ***three*** real roots, then at most ***two*** are in the interval $[-1,1]$, but the ***third*** one is outside it.